# .htaccess: Removing /index.php/foo

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site built with Contao. I just turned on URL rewriting and now `index.php/foo` returns a 404 error. I tried to rewrite `/index.php/foo` to `/foo` with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]
```

but it does not help.

Here's the rewrite part of the contao factory .htaccess with my additions in it's entirety (I edited out all the commented stuff to make it shorter):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/ # My rule here
  RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]    # My rule here

  <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g|js|css|ico|php|xml|csv|txt|gz|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|htm)$">
  RewriteEngine Off
  </FilesMatch>

  RewriteRule .*\.html$ index.php [L]

  RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/$ index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ $1/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the answer.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g|js|css|ico|THIS HERE CAUSED IT: --> ***php***|xml|csv|txt|gz|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|htm)$">
RewriteEngine Off
</FilesMatch>
```